# How do i install with makefile? I get erorr while typing `./configure`

Tags: drivers, compiling, intel, makefile

I'm trying to install Intel driver from here: http://intellinuxgraphics.org/2011Q4.html

However when running `./configure` and then `make` I get the following output:

```
$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to disable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking whether __clang__ is declared... no
checking whether __INTEL_COMPILER is declared... no
checking whether __SUNPRO_C is declared... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Werror=attributes... no
Package xorg-macros was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xorg-macros.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xorg-macros' found
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc -std=gnu99... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to i686-pc-linux-gnu format... 
func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... 
func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc -std=gnu99 object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc -std=gnu99 linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for GEN4ASM... no
checking for UDEV... no
checking for X11... no
checking whether to include SNA support... no
checking whether to include UXA support... yes
checking if RANDR is defined... no
checking if RENDER is defined... no
checking if XF86DRI is defined... no
checking if DPMSExtension is defined... no
checking for XORG... no
configure: error: Package requirements (xorg-server >= 1.6 xproto fontsproto pixman-1 >= 0.16 ) were not met:
No package 'xorg-server' found
No package 'xproto' found
No package 'fontsproto' found
No package 'pixman-1' found
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.
Alternatively, you may set the environment variables XORG_CFLAGS and XORG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

-

```
$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: The problem is clearly `configure: error: Package requirements ... were not met` -- i.e. you need to install the required build dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Well, exactly what it says: there is no file named `configure`. Are you in the right directory? Did you read the README or INSTALL file that comes with the package?

I wonder if this is what you want though. No offense, but if you can't understand the error message, compiling a videodriver might not be the right approach. What is it what you want to accomplish? Intel drivers are builtin, so you should have a good reason for this.

Comment: I feel i should update my driver because that on the laptop-S10e with intel 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2, videos in high quality both on youtube (for example) and on external hard driver connected to the laptop, doesn't run good enough and i want them to run smottly as normal. So i need to install this driver. if i have understood alright, i need to install the whole driver in parts-2d drver, 3d driver... could you please give me instruction for this driver? like if i put the extracted folder in my home/nir/Download what are the comand i sould type to the terminal?                   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to CD to the directory that contains the configure file. For example if the file is in `/home/your-username/Documents/folder-containing-configure`, you would open the Terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`, then type the path to the directory or paste it like so:

```
cd /home/your-username/Documents/folder-containing-configure
```

Then use `./configure`.

Comment: the configure command successeded, but when i type 'make' after the configure command finishde and i am in the same directory, i got error that it didn't found any makefile and i know there is in that folder. it called 'Makefile.in'.                                      thanks!

Comment: You should have some info regarding any errors provided in the terminal window. Also, does it say anything about a folder that contains the build info (errors)?

Comment: the process till the make command is in my question. up. i needed more to write.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to install build dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```